# JPA eclipse two foreign keys @IdClass implementation errors

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'm very new to Java EE and JPA/Eclipselink, so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a `@Id` for a table with no primary key and two composite keys, I tried to apply from a solution I read here by using `@IdClass` to mark the two foreign keys as a composite key, but I get this error when compiling and deploying the server.

Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.owl.server.objects.SaleDetails] and those of the entity bean class [class com.owl.server.objects.SaleDetails] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.. Please see server.log for more details.

Must I change the field types to be the same? Or is there another way?

Products table and corresponding Entity

[image: Products table]

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
   private String product_id;
   
   // ...
}
```

Sales Table and corresponding Entity

[image: Sales table]

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Sales")
public class Sale implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
    private int sale_id;

    // ...
}
```

Sale_details Table and Entity (Causes Errors)

[image: Sale_details table]

```java
public class SaleDetails implements Serializable {

    private int saleid_fk;
    private String productid_fk;
    private int quantity_sold;
    private String prescription;
    
    public SaleDetails() {
    }
    
    public SaleDetails(int saleid_fk, String productid_fk, int quantity_sold){
        this.saleid_fk = saleid_fk;
        this.productid_fk = productid_fk;
        this.quantity_sold = quantity_sold;
    }
}
```

Sale_details entity class

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(SaleDetails.class)
@Table(name = "sale_Details")
public class Sale_details {
    
   @Id
   private int saleid_fk;
    
   @Id
   private String productid_fk;
}
```

Here is the full stack trace error:

```
[2020-12-24 11:43:50,553] Artifact server:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [owlJPA] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7150] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.owl.server.objects.SaleDetails] and those of the entity bean class [class com.owl.server.objects.Sale_details] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Comment: The `SaleDetails` is used as its own `@IdClass`. The `@IdClass` should be a separate class. I cannot find the relevant paprt of the spec, but I would imagine that JPA needs some means to access the fields in the `IdClass`. Not sure if `private` fields are accessible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idclass value should not be the same class of Entity 'SaleDetails'

```
    @Entity
    @IdClass(PK.class)
    public static class SystemUser{
        @Id
        private String subsystem;

        @Id
        private String username;

        public PK getId(){
            return new PK(subsystem, username);
        }

        public void setId(PK id){
            this.subsystem = id.subsystem;
            this.username = id.username;
        }
    }

    public static class PK implements Serializable {

        private String subsystem;

        private String username;

        public PK(String subsystem, String username) {
            this.subsystem = subsystem;
            this.username = username;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so I should have two split the current Saledetails entity into two separate classes?

Comment: yes. in your code,SaleDetails is an Entity. if your want persist an object,  the value SaleDetails  is entity, the id (SaleDetails ) is also an entity. this may cause recursive reference.

Comment: I split the class as you suggested, but i get the same error, does this mean I have to change the table fields to be the same type, because currently one is INT and the other is a string.

Comment: no need. can you should me the complete code and the error stack traces?

Comment: i posted the code and error, thank you for taking the time and answering btw.

Comment: firstly, the id class SaleDetails should only contain the @Id fields only. move the extra fields to the value class Sale_details. secondly you should add get method for each field.

Answer (score 1):

You can used "derived identities"; and this is the way to map the relationships using an `@EmbeddedId`:

```java
@Embeddable
public class SaleDetailId {
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    String productId;  // corresponds to PK type of Product

    @Column(name = "sale_id")
    int saleId; // corresponds to PK type of Sale 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_details")
public class SaleDetail {
    @EmbeddedId
    SaleDetailId id;

    // id attribute mapped by join column default 
    @MapsId("saleId") // maps saleId attribute of embedded id 
    @ManyToOne
    private Sale sale;

    // id attribute mapped by join column default 
    @MapsId("productId") // maps productId attribute of embedded id 
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity_sold")
    private int quantitySold;
    
    public SaleDetails(Sale sale, Product product, int quantity_sold){
        this.sale = sale;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity_sold = quantity_sold;
    }
    // ...
}
```

To map the relationships using an `@IdClass`:

```java
public class SaleDetailId {
    int sale; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of Sale PK 
    String product;  // matches name of @Id attribute and type of Product PK
}


@Entity
@IdClass(SaleDetailId.class)
@Table(name = "sale_details")
public class SaleDetail {

    // id attribute mapped by join column default 
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sale_id")
    private Sale sale;

    // id attribute mapped by join column default 
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity_sold")
    private int quantitySold;
    
    public SaleDetails(Sale sale, Product product, int quantity_sold){
        this.sale = sale;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity_sold = quantity_sold;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: So if im getting this right, the (a)Embedded defines the composite key as product_id and sale_id, while the actual (a)Entity is whats being persisted by the entity manager. So do I need to write a one-to-many annotation in my sales and products? and when i want to instantiate a new sale with its corresponding sale_details, how do i do that?

Comment: You are not _required_ to add the corresponding one-to-many mappings to `Sale` and `Product`; but it might be helpful. I'm guessing it would be helpful for `Sale` and cumbersome for `Product` (as there would be an unmanageable number of `SaleDetail`s associated with each `Product`. Depending on your app's workflow, there are a number of ways you could instantiate a `Sale`; e.g. you could create a new `Sale` with an empty list of `SaleDetail`s, then add the details to the list, then save the sale to the datastore.

Comment: @BrianVosburgh I suppose this can not be made to work with `IdClass` if the ID field in "product" and "sale" are both called "id" (and are both of type Long)? The spec does not contain examples of derived entities with multiple parent entities...

Comment: @Warkst you should be able to use an `IdClass`. I have added an `IdClass` example to the answer. Even if both `Product` and `Sale` have an `id` attribute of type `Long`, the corresponding attributes in `SaleDetail` will have different names, i.e. `product` and `sale`.