# JPA composite key from two foreign keys in many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I currently have a simple database with three tables setup as below. I am simply trying to store the details of a sale (what products are purchased in the sale) via a many-to-many table that stores the saleid and the productid, along with how much of the product was purchased. This is the table setup:

I am using JPA with the clipselink implementation, I set the entities up this way:
[image]
Sale_id is the primary key for sales, product_id is the primary key for products, saleid_fk and productid_fk are both foreign keys that form a composite key.

Sale entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Sales")
public class Sale implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
    private int sale_id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Sale_Details",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "saleid_fk")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "productid_fk")}
    )
        private Set<Sale> sales = new HashSet<>();

     @Column(name = "grand_total", nullable = false)
        private double grand_total;

   //constructor, getters, setters
```

Products  entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="products")
    public class Product implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
        private String product_id;
    
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinTable(
                name = "Sale_Details",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "productid_fk")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "saleid_fk")}
        )
        private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
    
        @Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
        private String product_name;

    SaleDetails: 
    public class SaleDetails implements Serializable {
    
        private int saleid_fk;
        private String productid_fk;
    
        public SaleDetails(int saleid_fk, String productid_fk) {
            this.saleid_fk = saleid_fk;
            this.productid_fk = productid_fk;
        }
    }
```

Sale_Details Entity

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SaleDetails.class)
@Table(name = "sale_Details")
public class Sale_details {

    @Id
    private int saleid_fk;

    @Id
    private String productid_fk;

    private int quantity_sold;
    private String prescription;

    public Sale_details() {
    }

    public Sale_details(int saleid_fk, String productid_fk, int quantity_sold) {
        this.saleid_fk = saleid_fk;
        this.productid_fk = productid_fk;
        this.quantity_sold = quantity_sold;
    }
```

The problem when is when I tested by running this code to create a new sale,

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "owlJPA") 
        EntityManager em;
    
    @Transactional
        public String createSale(){
    
          Sale newsale = new Sale(100.0);
            em.persist(newSale);
            em.flush

          //i have a product with id of "A1" in my database, and persisting a sale by itself 
         works. 
          Sale_details newSale_detail = new Sale_details(newsale.getSale_id(), "A1", 20);
    
            em.persist(newSaleDetail);
            em.flush
    return "sucess";
    }
```

i get the following error:

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a
foreign key constraint fails (`owl_database`.`sale_details`, CONSTRAINT
`saledetails_sales_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`saleid_fk`) REFERENCES `sales` (`sale_id`))
Error Code: 1452

From what I understand reading other stackoverflow posts this is because JPA cannot determine the foreign keys of Sale and Product to create a composite primary key? But since I know that both the Sale and Product already Exist, what is going wrong here?

Comment: You might try the mappings I suggest in my response to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453062/1566345

Comment: You'll also need to fix the relationships, as the mapping from Sale-> Product and then Product->Sale are independent of the Sale_details entity, and will result in 3 different representations of the same data in that relationship table. They need to be fixed so they are Sale->Sale_details<-Product or you are going to get other problems down the line.